# In the below code, Even "synchronized" keyword is used , the threads are not synchronizing, Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronized

```
class A implements Runnable         //Thread class
{
        public void run()
        {
            read();
        }
        public synchronized void read()
        {
            for(int i= 0 ; i< 7 ;i++)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
        }
}

public class Main
{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             Thread t = new Thread(new A());
             t.setName("t1");

             Thread c = new Thread(new A());
             c.setName("t2");

            t.start();
            c.start();    
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: You are calling methods on two different threads

Answer (score 4):

Because they're synchronizing on different objects. Thread `t` synchs on `t` and `c` synchs on `c`.

If you create a shared object `f` and put `synchronized(f)` in the methods, it'll work as you intend.

For example put `private final static Object lock = new Object();` in your `A` class, and put `synchronized(lock) { // method body }` inside `read()`.

Comment: can u give me the correct code???

Comment: can you give me the correct code???

Answer (score 3):

You're synchronizing on different objects, on the `this` Thread created when the A object is created. For it to work you must synchronize on the one object, preferably an object created explicitly for this purpose. Also, a nitpick, don't extend Thread but instead implement Runnable.

Comment: can u give me the correct code??\

Comment: @RakeshTm: please don't ask for that as it makes you look lazy and as if you're begging others to do your homework for you. Best for you to try to create the correct code first yourself. If it doesn't work, then you can show us what you've tried, and we can help you.